# What is shortcut for setting primary key in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, shortcut

I am creating a table, how can I set primary key for my table without using my mouse ?
I wanna do this with my keyboard (short key).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with:  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd> (case insensitive).

That keyboard shortcut will mark as `PrimaryKey` of selected column (on design mode).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

P_Id is the column with the [primary key constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

**`ALTER TABLE Persons ADD PRIMARY KEY (P_Id);`**

then you click the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Question is, *What is the shortcut key?*

And I don't think **Sql Management Studio** has a shortcut key for adding **Primary Key** to a table.
I'm also sure that you can't assing a shortcut for **Set Primary Key** menu item.

Comment: Hello,maybe its too late but i see your answer now,look at @Elias-Hossain answer, it works fine my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure that you can do this, but here is a list of [shortcut keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx) for Sql Server Management Studio.

Maybe you could [create your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174178.aspx).

You could install [SSMS Tools](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) and create your own code snippet.